# How to make a multi-regional web application architecture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, web, database-design, cloud

My server is in Sweden (DB, ruby on rails web app, nginx). Sometimes people from South Africa and Southeast Asia come to my site.

For these people, the site is very stupid. Ping from Southeast Asia about 200ms. I want to solve this problem. I have no experience with such situations.

CDN will not help because it is only for static information.

I thought I need to make three servers for each region (1 server 1 nginx 1 webapp 1 base 1 region) and configure replication between databases. But I was told it was bad. How then? Maybe Amazon Cloud with RDS?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on AWS *could* use a [Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/what-is-load-balancing.html) with your service running on [multiple availability zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html).

This is the same on AWS or Google Cloud

There are however a few things to take into consideration, for instance:

- where is your db?
- is it distributed?
- is your service DB hungry?

Every scenario is easy to solve on AWS just by clicking around; meaning adding your service to multiple availability zones is as easy as making your db available across multiple regions as well.

Comment: `is it distributed? is your service DB hungry?`


I do not know what is this.

I have VPS, where installed the usual PostgreSQL 9.4 is.

I do not use AWS, I'm looking for solutions to the problem. If you can not do without AWS (or it's expensive), then I will be forced to use AWS.

Comment: you can do it without AWS, but you would need more infrastructure. You could have different hosts in different locations, but that'd kill your budget, hence I recommend AWS or Google Cloud, at least to begin with.

Comment: with database hungry I meant if DB access is a bottleneck in your service, then you also want a distributed database.

Comment: `You could have different hosts in different locations, but that'd kill your budget`
Do you have any examples of an article where I can read more about this?

`I recommend AWS or Google Cloud`

okay, thanks

Comment: The developer pages for both services are pretty good, they have nice guides that adjust your needs.

Comment: Now I understand what a distributed database is, thanks.

Comment: No, I want to read how it's done without AWS. AWS is good, but understanding best practices is also helpful.

Comment: how make this without AWS?

Comment: @deboyo if you intend to get that question resolved, you should open a new question instead of asking it on a comment. Accepting an answer as "answered" and then unmarking it just to add more details is pointless. Is this question accepted or not? The "how make this without AWS?" is a whole world on itself out of the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If your server provides a RESTful interface and you want to use AWS for any reason, I would recommend API Gateway, just because it already has an edge-optimization feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-basic-concept.html

"Edge-optimized API endpoint: The default host name of an API Gateway API that is deployed to the specified region while using a CloudFront distribution to facilitate client access typically from across AWS regions. API requests are routed to the nearest CloudFront Point of Presence (POP) which typically improves connection time for geographically diverse clients. An API is edge-optimized if you do not explicitly specify its endpoint type when creating the API."

Comment: Thanks, but I would not like to use Amazon services.